# How to properly update Node js in windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to update my Node js to the current LTS version on my windows 7. Do I just let the current version be, and install the latest version from the website? Or do I need to delete the currently installed node? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Not a real answer, but I cannot recommend [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) enough

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to have multiple versions of Node is by using nvm.

[Nvm for Windows (guide)](https://codeburst.io/nvm-for-windows-how-to-install-and-use-13b7a4209791)

[Nvm for Windows (GitHub repo)](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Comment: Do I need to uninstall the current nodejs before installing nvm?

Comment: it is better to uninstall so you work only with nvm

Answer (score 8):

Goto https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Download the version you want, for instance msi for windows. Run the download and it will update the version to the one you have downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the latest stable version. Please use the below comments with the administrator command prompt

```
nvm install lts
```

Once complete the installation. You received the message

> Downloading node.js version 16.15.1 (64-bit)...
> Extracting...
> Complete
> Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type
> nvm use 16.15.1

next step

```
nvm use 16.15.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since npm installs Node.JS as a package (just like it would React or any other package) to your project, you can just 'npm install node' to get the latest version.

If you're looking for npm, the [NPM](https://npmjs.com/get-npm/) website says this:

> To update your npm, type this into your terminal:
>
> `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: I believe when you make a project, you install Nodejs as a package, so it should be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Follow https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version you can find several ways to update the node.

Answer (score 0):

Install `nvm` by running:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash in bash
or
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

Then run the editor as administrator :

`nvm install 14.18.1` (example the node version that you want or use lts for the latest)

`nvm use 14.18.1`

Make sure the node version to be used is the one installed after `nvm install`. If you already have one, delete it first.

`node -v` will give **14.18.1**